# OpenNetCf - C# into VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I tried to translate this piece of code in VB but I can't figure out how to do it...Can anyone show me how is the translation?

Thank you

```
private void WatchForDrives()
{
  DeviceStatusMonitor monitor = new DeviceStatusMonitor(DeviceClass.FileSystem, false);
  monitor.StartStatusMonitoring();
  monitor.DeviceNotification += delegate(object sender, DeviceNotificationArgs e)
    { 
    string message = string.Format("Disk '{0}' has been {1}.", e.DeviceName,       e.DeviceAttached ? "inserted" : "removed");
    MessageBox.Show(message, "Disk Status");
    };
 }
```

Comment: What version of .NET? And the conversion is rather trivial if you did simple googling.

Comment: Thanks...I tried it but doesn't work. I'm using Compact framework 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only VB 10 supports multiline lambdas, so you will have to create a separate method to handle the event. This should work regardless of compiler:

```
Private Sub WatchForDrives()
    Dim monitor As New DeviceStatusMonitor(DeviceClass.FileSystem, False)
    monitor.StartStatusMonitoring()
    AddHandler monitor.DeviceNotification, AddressOf MonitorDeviceNotified
End Sub

Private Sub MonitorDeviceNotified(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DeviceNotificationArgs)
    Dim message As String = String.Format("Disk '{0}' has been {1}.", e.DeviceName, If(e.DeviceAttached, "inserted", "removed"))
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

http://converter.telerik.com/

```
Private Sub WatchForDrives()
    Dim monitor As New DeviceStatusMonitor(DeviceClass.FileSystem, False)
    monitor.StartStatusMonitoring()
    monitor.DeviceNotification += Function(sender As Object, e As DeviceNotificationArgs) Do
        Dim message As String = String.Format("Disk '{0}' has been {1}.", e.DeviceName, If(e.DeviceAttached, "inserted", "removed"))
        MessageBox.Show(message, "Disk Status")
    End Function
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work...gives error after "Do" statement